# Why does my data plan need to be on to send pictures with text?

Tags: photos

I don't understand why data is needed to send a picture with a text or to send a text to multiple recipients. These things did not need data on a dumb phone. They just used texting.

Comment: Dumb-phones also use mobile data to send multimedia messages. It is just that with most dumb phones, the carrier includes this data access as part of the messaging package you are subscribed to. Most carriers require a data plan on a smart device because it has the potential to use significantly more data.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're speaking about the [Short Message Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service): For sending pictures *without* text, that's done via a special "signal channel", where exactly 160 bytes fit into a single package (hence the limit of 160 chars). But when you want to include more (more text, multi-media elements like pictures or video, or some other attachments), those "additional data" don't fit into this "package" – so your message is switched to [MMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service).

Other than SMS, MMS are sent and received via mobile data (often via a special Access Point configured in your device). So this is the reason why it requires your data plan to send "pictures with text": you basically switch to a different service. Details can be found behind the links, if needed.